# Understanding of Kolmogorov's 0-1 law.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

[image]

I really don't understand why the event $x_1+...+x_n\ge 0$ infinity often belongs to the present ${\cal F}_{\infty}$ but not to Kolmogorov's tail field and I really have no idea about how to prove this. I will be so grateful if anyone could kindly help with that. Thanks.

Comment: You can find one proof on p.154 in Durrett https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf